# Parse By Delimitor with sqldf

Tags: r, sqldf

I have a dataframe like below:

```
df
   ColA    ColB
  New|ME      7
 New|You      8
     ten      9
Aim|High     10
```

Expected Output:

```
   ColA    ColB    First   Second
  New|ME      7      New       ME
 New|You      8      New      You
     ten      9      ten       NA
Aim|High     10      Aim     High
```

How do I parse ColA using sqldf by the delimitor `|`?

This was my attempt but I received an error:

```
library(sqldf)
df1<- sqldf("SELECT * FROM df CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT([ColA], '|') ")

Error in result_create(conn@ptr, statement) : near "(": syntax error
```

Comment: Google *sqlite functions* to find out what functions SQLite provides.  Also RSQLite provides the functions listed in `library(RSQLite); help("initExtension")`   In this case you should be able to do it using `instr` and `substr`.

Comment: thank you, that helped get my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df <- sqldf("SELECT *, SUBSTR([ColA], 1, INSTR([ColA],'|')-1) First FROM df")
df <- sqldf("SELECT *, SUBSTR([ColA], INSTR([ColA],'|')+1, Length([ColA])) Second FROM df")
df <- sqldf("SELECT ColA, ColB, First, Second FROM df")
```

Comment: Suggest combining these all into one `select` statement.  Also note that you can omit the 3rd argument in `substr` if you want everything remaining.